# jQuery Sortable Plugin

Tags: jquery, html

On my current project I'm working with jQuery's sortable plugin in a table.

The table I'm working with consists of football players and they can be arranged in whatever order from 1 to the amount of players in the table.

Sometimes some of the players will have to be locked in which case a user won't be able to move them around, only the unlocked players can be moved.

When players are locked they are set aside to the top half of the table while the editable players are at the bottom half. The 2 halves are organized in their own way but what I want is everything to be merged and organized as one big table

Any help on how I can merge to table bodies to show organized table rows starting from 1?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cesFR.png (Here's a screenshot to help you)

This is my table (HTML)

```
  <tbody id="locked_players">

 </tbody>

 <tbody id="players_of_rank">

 </tbody>
```

Jquery

```
 $('#players_of_rank').sortable();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would say to merge the ewo tables into one and keep it like that:http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/ssocyc0h/

```
$("#players_of_rank > tbody:last").append($("#locked_players > tbody").html());
$("#locked_players").remove();
$("#players_of_rank").sortable();
```

Hope it helps!